# JPanel Object To Rest On the Bottom

Tags: java, swing, layout, constructor

I have a simple Class called BallTask that lets a ball move around and bounce off the limits of the frame. I am trying to apply buttons that I can use to stop the thread and start it but I am stuck on getting the button panel to stick to the bottom.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setContentPane(new BallTask());

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
            JButton start = new JButton("Start");

            buttons.add(start);
            buttons.add(stop);

            window.add(buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I can imagine the issue is to do with setting the window.setContentPane however, BallTask is only a Jpanel so I thought if I added another panel it would just go underneath it due to the layout. The buttons however appear but at the top of the Frame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making `BallTask` your content pane. So te `buttons` is being added to the `BallTask`.  A `JPanel` (BallTask) has a default `FlowLayout`. If you want `BallTask` to occupy the `CENTER` and `buttons` to occupy the `SOUTH`, just `window.add(new BallTask())` instead of `setContentPane(new BallTask())`. Or, set the layout of `BallTask` to `BorderLayout` if you want `buttons` on the `BallTask` panel at the bottom.

Comment: @ppeskillet Such an obvious solution. Thank you. Will tick when ready